# Debugging a GSON model class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gson, breakpoints

My model class is -

```
public class ModelClass {

  @SerializedName("a")
  String abc;
}
```

Now how do I put breakpoints(conditional as well) on the field `abc`?

Comment: What do you want to debug, reads/writes to that field?

Comment: Yes. Basically, if I give this a json like {"a" : "hello world"}, I want to debug it.

Comment: It sounds like an IDE-related question heavily. You might try to use field breakpoints and trace the read/write operations. Or you need it programmatically?

Comment: No I want to use breakpoints on a jetBrains based IDE.

Comment: IntelliJ-based IDEs support `Ctrl+F8` keystroke on a field to set a field breakpoint. Did you try it?

Comment: Ya I did that. But for GSON, it shows a '-' sign on the field.

Comment: Such a breakpoint breaks the execution flow once field read/write occurs. if you want to debug the particular field value, you must debug the way how the value is instantiated elsewhere (in its class) or how the value is being set up (say, put a breakpoint on `String.value`). This is probably the most IntelliJ can give you.

Comment: Next thing, Gson works in mostly streaming fashion and it holds no entire JSON document (this might be too memory consuming, and that's a justified design choice). If you want to debug a particular type hierarchy, you have to implement your own type adapter that could consume a value to a `JsonElement` representation, so you could see it in your debugger, and then delegate the tree (not the stream!) to the downstream parser. I don't believe field breakpoints can give you much.